# regex - How to match elements while ignoring others between quotation marks?

Tags: java, regex

I can't seem to find the regex that suits my needs.

I have a .txt file of this form:

```
Abc "test" aBC : "Abc aBC" 
Brooking "ABC" sadxzc : "I am sad"
asd : "lorem"
a22 : "tactius"
testsa2 : "bruchia"
test : "Abc aBC"
b2 : "Ast2"
```

From this .txt file I wish to extract everything matching this regex "**([a-zA-Z]\w+)**", except the ones between the quotation marks.

I want to rename every word (except the words in quotation marks), so I should have for example the following output:

```
A "test " B : "Abc aBC" 
Z "ABC" X : "I am sad"
Test : "lorem"
F : "tactius"
H : "bruchia"
Game : "Abc aBC"
S: "Ast2"
```

Is this even achievable using a regex? Are there alternatives without using regex?

Comment: Based on your file format it seems more like you want to rename the things that are before the colon (`:`) and leave the stuff after alone... which is easier than dealing with everything inside and outside of quotes differently. Is this an accurate assessment? ***ETA:*** Post was updated and this question is now irrelevant, as this is obviously not an accurate assessment.

Comment: Is this Json? Because the Json format is more compilcated. You better use a library for this.

Comment: Ok, i made a small edit with the file format. I'm using java for this task. No, it's not Json.

Comment: `Abc` becomes `A` and Brooking becomes `Z`? That's a mightily complicated regex we're looking at.

Comment: Yep, that was my exact thought.

Comment: So "how" exactly does Brooking become Z? What does your mapping look like?

Comment: First I would like to extract all the words matching the Regex, and then replacing them for the new output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If quotes are balanced and there is no escaping in the input like `\"` then you can use this regex to match words outside double quotes:

```
(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)(\b[a-zA-Z]\w+\b)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wM2bH0/1)

In java it will be:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)(\\b[a-zA-Z]\\w+\\b)");
```

This regex will match word if those are outside double quotes by using a lookahead to make sure there are even number of quotes after each matched word.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for, thank you very much. You just helped me a lot. (Yes, the quotation marks are balanced)

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach might be to split the string by `"`, then do the replace using your regex on every odd part (on parts 1, 3, ..., if you start the numbering from 1), and join everything back.

**UPD**
However, it is also simple to implement manually. Just go along the line and track whether you are inside quotes or not.

```
insideQuotes = false
result = ""
currentPart = ""
input = input + '"' // so that we do not need to process the last part separately
for ch in string
    if ch == '"'
        if not insideQuotes
            currentPart = replace(currentPart)
        result = result + currentPart + '"'
        currentPart = ""
        insideQuotes = not insideQuotes
    else 
        currentPart = currentPart + ch
drop the last symbol of result (it is that quote mark that we have added)
```

---

However, think also on whether you will need some more advanced syntax. For example, quote escaping like

```
word "inside quote \" still inside" outside again
```

? If yes, then you will need a more advanced parser, or you might think of using some special format.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t formulate a “within quotes” condition the way you might think. But you can easily search for unquoted words *or* quoted strings and take action only for the unquoted words:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"|([a-zA-Z]\\w+)");
for(String s: lines) {
    Matcher m=p.matcher(s);
    while(m.find()) {
        if(m.group(1)!=null) {
            System.out.println("take action with "+m.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

This utilizes the fact that each search for the next match starts at the end of the previous. So if you find a quoted string (`"[^"]*"`) you don’t take any action and continue searching for other matches. Only if there is no match for a quoted string, the pattern looks for a word (`([a-zA-Z]\w+)`) and if one is found, the group 1 captures the word (will be non `null`).